# matplotlib plots in Cylindrical and Spherical coordinate systems

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

For example, if I wanted to create polar coordinates plot I could use this code:

```
self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
```

But I did not find any 'Cylindrical' or 'Spherical' projections.

Does anyone know how to create these plots?

Comment: cylindrical and spherical are 3d projections, aren't they? matplotlib is mostly a 2d plotting facility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it's useful for your task:http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/cyl.html